# Downgrade TypeScript in Visual Studio to 1.7

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015

I recently updated VS2015 to Update 2, which updated typescript to 1.8. Unfortunately it caused some problems with my code so I had to uninstall it. However, reverting the Update 2 did not revert typescript and Visual Studio "Extensions and Update" is still pointing to TypeScript 1.8 even though it does not exist anymore. The "disable" and "uninstall" button for TypeScript in the VS manager is not enabled.

How do I make Visual Studio downgrade the TypeScript version to the one currently installed in my machine, TypeScript 1.7?

Comment: Which kind of issue? Could you give us an exemple?

Comment: If you mean for typescript. Typescript files are now being opened like text files, no colour coding or intellisense. It does not compile either. TypescriptBuild in the project properties now show this error message:

An error occurred trying to load the page.
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, Version=1.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Comment: If you mean the problem with Update 2, VS Git keeps trying to add all files that are in the directory, ignoring the rules in .gitignore

Answer (score 1):

I posted a similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46569568/typescript-1-8-for-visual-studio-2017/48672997#48672997).

Essentially, download the Microsoft.Typescript.MSBuild nuget package that corresponds to your desired version number.

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem is caused by a bug of "TypeScript for Visual Studio 2015" (un)installer.
And VS2015 Update1 has same problem. Not only on Update2.

I found TypeScript 1.8.6 can not uninstall correctly (I think 1.7 two).
I think this problem is caused by timings.

If uninstall not correctly, 1.8.6 is removed from control panel.
But registry is still polluted. So VS2015 says "1.8.6 installed".

---

Next, uninstalled 1.8.6, we can not compile on 1.7.

Both "TypeScript for Visual Studio 2015" 1.7 and 1.8 use same folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\TypeScript`.
And if uninstalled 1.8.6, not restored to 1.7.

This problem cause a similar problem.
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7445

On this problem and doing solution of comment, we must re-install 1.7.
But installer of 1.7 found 1.8.6 on registry, and skipped override 1.8 files in `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\TypeScript`.
Finally, installer of 1.7 says "Setup Completed!".

As a result, VS2015 can not work with TypeScript 1.7.
This logs are found in `dd_TypeScript_Full_yyyyMMddHHmmss.log` on Temp folder.

---

Finally, I found **limited (and risky)** solution.

1. Both uninstall 1.7 and 1.8.6
2. Clear files in `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\TypeScript`
3. Execute regedit and search `TypeScript Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2015` with `DisplayVersion = 1.8.6`.
   It found as `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Products\0B661F28DFD57E44496FC70DB01B910A\InstallProperties]`  .
4. Delete `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Products\0B661F28DFD57E44496FC70DB01B910A\]`.
5. Re-install 1.7

Why limited?
My VS2015 and Roslyn says my TypeScript project is running on 1.4.
But can compile 1.7.

If you faced this problem by 1.7.4 and 1.7.6, Search "TypeScript Power Tool" and remove 1.7.6.