# TypeScript 1.8 for Visual Studio 2017

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2017

I have a project created in Visual Studio 2015 which using TypeScript 1.8. After installing Visual Studio 2017, I tried to open the old project in the new IDE.
If I check properties of the project, I get this:

> TypeScript version: 1.8 (unavailable).

[image]

However, I can see that this version is already under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.8`.

I don't want to use a newer version because I don't want to change the code right now.

Does Visual Studio 2017 support TypeScript 1.8?

How can I make this version available to VS 2017?

Comment: Not to sure if you got this working but please let me know. I had it working fine and then I uninstalled VS 2015 and it no longer worked. Doing so must have removed 1.8 TS. Now can't seem to find an installer download for the compiler. Modifying the install doesnt have it either.

Comment: I'll note that I am probably just going to use 2.3 and fix the errors that its saying are there. Obviously cause its JS I cans till run just annoying seeing redlines cause it seems the definition files were updated? Not sure how thought they might be seperate to my vs2017 update

Answer (score 14):

I was able to solve this problem by installing the corresponding version nuget package of [Microsoft.TypeScript.MsBuild](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild/). So for us it is version 1.8.11.

The TypesScript version still says 'unavailable' and there are still some intellisense errors shown. However, the project builds and runs properly.

Alternatively, if a user wants a higher version. Microsoft makes some version tooling available as a visual studio extension (e.g. version 2.7 https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TypeScriptTeam.typescript-27-vs2017)

UPDATE: I have figured out the intellisense errors. You can go to Tools > Extensions and Updates and install typescript tools for a version greater than 2.6. Then you can you the //@ts-ignore suppression comments described [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html)

Side note: I did not have any luck resolving the intellisense errors. I tried

- Installing the Microsoft.TypeScript.Compiler nuget package for 1.8
- Installing various versions of the TSLint nuget package
- Installing the TSLint.MSBuild nuget package
- Installing the TypeScript Analyzer (a static analysis extension for TSLint)

Comment: If you're not sure what version you need, right click project, select Properties -> TypeScript Build, and note the version shown. Try to select the version of the nuget package closest to that TypeScript version.  If you select a version much newer than you are using, it may still fail because of breaking changes in the TypeScript that aren't compatible with old syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Installing the version at [enter link description here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TypeScriptTeam.TypeScript182forVisualStudio2013) worked for me.

Comment: Sooo, basically just re-installing the old 2013 version of TS, and that worked for VS 2017?